# How to take the first record that matches a certain query in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, pipeline, aggregation

I have a question. I have a MongoDB aggregation that needs to give me a certain output. But I'm not sure how to do it. Let me give you a little context:

I have a table with sessions. I have matched the sessions, so I only get the sessions that have sales. In the same row, I have the previous session of that sale. Now the thing is that I only want those previous sessions as output, which session_time is before the session_time with the order. If there was a sale on another session before my initial session, then I don't need the sessions before that session.

Let me give you an example:

```
session_id, session_time, previous_session_id, previous_session_time, previous_session_has_sale

10, 2019-08-07 18:00:00, 9, 2019-08-07 17:45:00, true
9, 2019-08-07 17:45:00, 8, 2019-08-07 15:23:00, false
8, 2019-08-07 15:23:00, 7, 2019-05-21 14:34:00, false
7, 2019-05-21 14:34:00, 6, 2019-04-24 17:45:00, true
6, 2019-04-24 17:45:00, 5, 2018-11-21 15:23:00, false
5, 2018-11-21 15:23:00, 4, 2018-11-21 14:34:00, false
```

So I only want the records with order_id 10, 9, 8 and 7. The records before order_id 7 are not relevant.

How can I build this in my aggregation pipeline? I was hoping for some sort of $first, but that operator may only be used in the $group stage. I need it in a $match or $project stage...

Please help me out!

Comment: can you share I/O required, the current query you have worked on and sample DB collection on which you're querying

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not possible due to confidentiality reasons. The data, as shown above, is what I need for this to work. That is also the output from my current aggregation pipeline. My question is how to make it work so that I get the required output in following aggregation stages...

Comment: you want documents after document having previous_session_has_sale true giving documents with session_id 7,8,9,10 in result?

Comment: can you elaborate on your requirements/conditions for aggregate pipeline

Comment: "wich session_time is before the session_time with the order", " another session before my initial session" these terms are not understandable

Comment: Use the aggregation $limit operator. Refer - http://www.dba86.com/docs/mongo/2.4/reference/operator/aggregation/limit.html

Comment: try below pipeline https://mongoplayground.net/p/EO6O8NEf-tl